# How to use SurfaceView to overlay another SurfaceView and why canvas be null?

Tags: android, virtual-machine, android-canvas, surfaceview

I'm trying to use `SurfaceView` with `Canvas` to draw a waveform. I'm using one `SurfaceView` with `Canvas` to draw, and it works.

But when I want to make my first `SurfaceView` overlay by the second `SurfaceView`(using `FrameLayout`). It's doesn't work.

And these two questions appears to me:

```
  1. If I use Canvas in second SurfaceView, then the second canvas becomes null;

  2. If I don't use Canvas in second SurfaceView, but just call overlay, then the SurfaceView size will be overlay but the graph is same.
```

Referenced code is as below:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.e("onCreate", "here");
    l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l1);
    l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l2);
    l2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    sfv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.sfv);
    sfh = sfv.getHolder();
    sfv.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


    sfv2 = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.sfv2);
    sfh2 = sfv2.getHolder();
    sfv2.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint2.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint2.setStrokeWidth(3);
    Log.i("flow", "now at before init()");
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    sfh.addCallback(this);
    sfh2.addCallback(this);
    //init();
}

public void init() {
    Log.e("init", "here");
   if (pic) {
        canvas = sfh.lockCanvas(new Rect(xtime, 0, xtime + 2, getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()));
        canvas.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
            a = 600 - i;
            canvas.drawLine(xtime, oldy, xtime + 2, a, paint);
            xtime += 2;
            oldy = a;
            if (xtime > 1000) {
                xtime = 0;
                oldy = 0;
            }
        }
        sfh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
       // tv.setText("in the init2");
   }
    else{
       Log.e("sfh2", "here");
       canvas = sfh2.lockCanvas(new Rect(xtime2, 0, xtime2 + 2, getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()));
       if(canvas == null){
           Log.e("canvas", "null here");
       }
       else {
           canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
           for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
               a = 300 - i;
               canvas.drawLine(xtime2, oldy, xtime2 + 2, a, paint2);
               xtime2 += 2;
               oldy = a;
               if (xtime2 > 1000) {
                   xtime2 = 0;
                   oldy2 = 0;
               }
           }
           sfh2.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
       }
   }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.e("surfaceCreated", "here");
    init();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    Log.e("surfaceChanged", "here");
    init();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.e("surfaceDestroyed", "here");

}

public void onchange(View view) {
    if (pic) {
        pic = false;
        l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        l2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tv.setText("change sf2");
        Log.e("pic", "pic " + pic);
    } else {
        pic = true;
        l1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv.setText("change sf1");
        Log.e("pic", "pic " + pic);
    }

}
```

I have been in confusion for two weeks, hope somebody can help me to resolve this issue. 
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, bear in mind that a SurfaceView has two parts, the Surface and the View.  The View part acts like any other View.  The Surface is created asynchronously, and is a completely separate layer.

Your current code is creating two overlapping Surfaces with the same Z-ordering, which means they're trying to occupy the same space at the same time.  The results are undefined, but generally speaking you will see one Surface but not the other.  Use e.g. [`setZOrderMediaOverlay()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay(boolean)) on the one that should be in front of the other.  See [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "multi-surface test" Activity for an example with three overlapping Surfaces.

The Surfaces are created asynchronously, and not at the same time, so you should expect your `surfaceCreated()` callback to fire twice.  It looks like you're calling `init()` each time.  If it first fires for Surface A, and `init()` tries to draw on Surface B, the method will fail, because it's trying to draw on a Surface that hasn't been created yet.  Check the value of SurfaceHolder in `surfaceCreated()`, and and only draw on the Surface that was just created.  (Alternatively, wait until they've both been created, and then draw on both.)